# How to put an image at a specific part of an UIImageVIew

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

i am very new on this platform and what i am trying is that show an UIImage of 50*50 size on  UIImageVIew of 1024 * 768. But problem is that i want to show an image on CGRECTMAKE(10,60,50,50).position. means at a specific portion of an image.Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Read the faq - http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Please update the question with what you have tried so far with code.

Comment: @viraj. please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951576/how-to-place-a-uiimage-over-another-uiimage

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after - but have you tried using [UIImage drawInRect:] on the image?